# How to get JOptionPane's exit value

Tags: java, joptionpane

sorry if this has already been asked but I can't find it anywhere. I made a custom `JOptionPane` with a `JSlider`. It does what it is supposed to do, but how can I check if the pressed ok or cancel? Because right now it does it anyway.

**Code:**

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
JSlider slider = getSlider(optionPane);
slider.setValue(value);
optionPane.setMessage(new Object[]{"Select a value: ", slider});
optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
optionPane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
optionPane.createDialog(parent, title).setVisible(true);

// get return value of optionPane
```

I've gone through the methods and didn't find it, that doesn't mean; howerever, that it's not there.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) has a nice example for the way you are creating the dialog.

A short snippet of the documentation:

```
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
dialog.show();
Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();
if(selectedValue == null)
  return CLOSED_OPTION;
//If there is not an array of option buttons:
if(options == null) {
  if(selectedValue instanceof Integer)
     return ((Integer)selectedValue).intValue();
  return CLOSED_OPTION;
}
```

Looks like the `pane.getValue()` after you `show()` the dialog will have the resulting value.

You may wish to restructure your code to use the more easily usable `showOptionDialog` method as described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494222/how-to-handle-cancel-button-in-joptionpane).

Comment: Thanks; however, `pane.getValue()` returns `JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION` which is two, when it is canceled, not null. And `dialog.show()' is deprecated.

Comment: the related question linked might be a cleaner and easier way to go